# Calculating the Number of Distinct Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that there exists a graph of 5 vertices with the degree sequence: $(1,2,2,2,3)$.

Is there a way to count the total number of distinct graphs possible given these constraints? Or do we need more constraints?

Comment: For clarification, are you asking for the number of labeled graphs? or just for up to isomorphism?  If just up to isomorphism, ask yourself the question of whether the degree one vertex is adjacent or is not adjacent to the degree three vertex.

Comment: @JMoravitz What I was trying to get at was the number of labeled graphs.Thank you.

Comment: Well there are only two unlabelled graphs for your degree sequence up to isomorphism...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection there are only two possible graphs up to isomorphism.  A formal argument can be made, but it should be rather self-explanatory.  It begins by making the choice of whether or not the degree 1 vertex is next to the degree 3 vertex.  Once that decision has been made, there are no further choices to be made as the locations of the remaining vertices and edges is forced.

```
           vertex of degree 1 is adjacent to vertex of degree 3
           *------*------#------*
                   \           /
                    -----#-----

           vertex of degree 1 is not adjacent to vertex of degree 3
           *------*------*---#
                          \ /
                           #
```

Vertices labeled # are indistinguishable above whereas each vertex labeled * above is distinguishable.  (*There is only one vertex of degree $2$ which is not adjacent to the vertex of degree 3 in the first graph, while there is only one vertex of degree $2$ which is adjacent to the vertex of degree $1$ in the second type*)

To count how many labeled graphs there are satisfying these conditions, we approach via multiplication principle:

- Pick which of the two types of graphs it is
- Pick the label of the degree 1 vertex
- Pick the label of the degree 3 vertex
- Pick the label of the distinguishable degree 2 vertex

There are then $2\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 120$ such graphs.